# How can I keep a center-aligned page from cutting-off the LEFT side when it doesn't fit on screen?

Tags: html, css, ipad, internet-explorer, alignment

I have a page that is centered and it gets cut-off on the LEFT side on iPads and some browsers, especially if the content is wider than the screen. How can I ensure the left side doesn't get cut off (or that it aligns left if the screen is too narrow)? Here is the page: 
http://nextgenhealth.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using **CSS3 media queries**.

For example, set a threshold for when your content would switch from being centered to be being anchored to the left.

In your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* styles for when the browser is left than 600px in width */
    #site-body-content {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* style content when our browser is greater than 600px in width */
    #site-body-content {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -600px;
    }
}
```

That should cover mobile safari but unfortunately media queries are only supported in IE from version 9 onwards. Compatibility info: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Alternatively, you could check the browser width on load and listen to window resize events in Javascript and update your CSS accordingly.